# Deploying Event Reciever on the production environment

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, production

I want to deploy the event receiver created in SharePoint 2010 to the production environment.  This is a farm solution, but I have a question regarding the deployment in the production environment.  Should event receiver be deployed globally or should they be deployed as web application targeted solution in the production environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you WSP contains only Event Receiver, and no web.config entries (which event receivers do not need), it will always appear as "Globally Deployed" in central administration. Even if you try to target to specific web application, you may get following error:

[image]

If it contains other artifacts which requires web.config entries, I suggest you deploy to only those web applications which needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it available globally? Remember you won't have visual studio on your production farm (or at least you definitely shouldn't), so you can deploy to wherever you specify in PowerShell or via the UI.

Comment: This solution is basically specific to a custom list in a site collection..but are there any pros or cons as to such kind of event receiver being deployed globally or to a targeted web application .Thanks

Comment: Well if it's an Item Event Receiver targeted to one list, it will only ever be used in the web application where that list exists. In this specific instance, I'm not sure there are any pros or cons to having the event receiver specific to a web application or globally. This would be answered differently if the event receiver was part of a deployment package solution that contained other artefacts.